# Command with a first parameter discord.User but it also has a sub command discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I have 2 commands, the main one is `?warnings {optional: @user} {optional: page (int)}` and the other is `?warnings list {optional: @user} {optional: page (int)}`. The 2nd one is a subcommand, how would I implement them without causing a badArgument because the first arg should be a discord.User,  not `str`?
At the moment, my code is like this:

```
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.group()
async def warnings(self, ctx, user: discord.User=None, warning: int=1):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
         #do stuff

@commands.guild_only()
@warnings.group(aliases=["list", "listwarns", "warnlist"])
async def listwarnings(self, ctx, user: discord.User=None, warning: int=1):
     #do stuff
```

Comment: Try passing [`invoke_without_command=True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group.invoke_without_command) to the `commands.group` decorator.  That should mean that the coroutine only gets called if there is no subcommand. I don't know if that will happen early enough though.